# HTML ID returning as "Undefined" with javascript console.log?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a system that gives an item an ID using javascript, and the next part takes the id and saves it (for now, it'll log it), however when I try to log it, the ID returns as undefined when called outside of the same function the ID was set in.

```js
//vars for add
let newItem;
let listNewItem;
let appended;
let idNum;
//the variable that helps list how many items have the class name of listItem
let listItemAmount = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

// adds the button to the end of the new to-do items
const buttonCode = ' <br><button class="deletebutton" onclick="del(this.id)"></button><button class="checkbutton">✔</button>'


//vars for remove
let deleteBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("deletebutton");

//listens for button click to exeute the add function
document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener('click', add);


//add a new task
function add() {

  // get value of the new item
  newItem = prompt("What is the name of your new task?");

  //create element
  listNewItem = document.createElement('li');
  listNewItem.innerHTML = newItem + buttonCode;
  listNewItem.classList.add("listItem");
  idNum = listItemAmount.length;
  listNewItem.id = 'item' + idNum;
  console.log(listNewItem.id);

  //append element
  appended = document.getElementById("list");
  appended.appendChild(listNewItem);
}

//deletes a task
function del(id) {
  console.log('id:', id.id);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title">
    <h1>To Do</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="topmain">
      <button id="addButton">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
      <li class="listItem">Go Outside <br><button class="deletebutton" onclick="del(this)"></button><button class="checkbutton">✔</button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried console.log-ing the id using this.id placed in the parameters in the function and directly in the function.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Because there isn't an `id` on the button element. There is an `id` on the parent `div`, which is what you seem to be trying to get.

Comment: isn't del(this) passing the button element and not the li?  have you tried id.parentElement.id in you del function?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what's wrong. When I push the Add button, the console logs what it is supposed to (item1, item2, etc.).

Comment: The problem was solved. Thank you all so much for your help! It turned out that I was overthinking it and it grabbed the ID of the button, and not the li. Thanks again to everyone for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your `buttonCode`, `this` in `del(this)` refers to the `<button>` element but not its parent element `listItem`. You may use `target.parentElement` to get its parent first and then gets its `id`:

```js
//vars for add
let newItem;
let listNewItem;
let appended;
let idNum;
//the variable that helps list how many items have the class name of listItem
let listItemAmount = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

// adds the button to the end of the new to-do items
const buttonCode = ' <br><button class="deletebutton" onclick="del(this)"></button><button class="checkbutton">✔</button>'


//vars for remove
let deleteBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("deletebutton");

//listens for button click to exeute the add function
document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener('click', add);


//add a new task
function add() {

  // get value of the new item
  newItem = prompt("What is the name of your new task?");

  //create element
  listNewItem = document.createElement('li');
  listNewItem.innerHTML = newItem + buttonCode;
  listNewItem.classList.add("listItem");
  idNum = listItemAmount.length;
  listNewItem.id = 'item' + idNum;
  console.log(listNewItem.id);

  //append element
  appended = document.getElementById("list");
  appended.appendChild(listNewItem);
}

//deletes a task
function del(target) {
  console.log('id:', target.parentElement.id);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title">
    <h1>To Do</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="topmain">
      <button id="addButton">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
      <li class="listItem" id="first-item">Go Outside <br><button class="deletebutton" onclick="del(this)"></button><button class="checkbutton">✔</button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```